# loops & string processing error due to logical flaw - python

Tags: string, python-2.7, loops, if-statement

I have a list of tags and am trying to break some tags that contain more than one word.

data = ['Open Source','Software Development','JavaScript','Technology','Web Development' 'Programming','Mobile Development','Technology','Professionals' 'Software' 'HTML5'],[..]....]

My code for cleaning up the data and keeping some unique tags -

```
def break_tags(data):

big_tags = []
for n in range(len(data)):

    tags = []

    for item in data[n][5:23]:
        if item != nan:
            if 'open source' in str(item).lower():
                tags.append('open source')
            if 'data science' in str(item).lower():
                tags.append('data science')

            else:
                item = str(item).lower().split(' ')
                tags.extend([e.strip("'():,&;+?][ ") for e in item if e not in remove])
    big_tags.append(tags)
return big_tags
```

Result after running the break_tags(data)

original_list1 - **['Open Source'** 'Software Development' 'JavaScript' 'Technology','Web Development' 'Programming','Mobile Development','Technology','Professionals' 'Software' 'HTML5']

new_list1 - [**'open source', 'open', 'source'**, 'software', 'development',
       'javascript', 'technology', 'web', 'development', 'programming',
       'mobile', 'development', 'technology', 'professionals', 'software',
       'html5']

original list2:['Data Management', 'Cloud Computing', 'Big Data', 'Data Analytics',
       'Data Visualization', 'Predictive Analytics', 'NoSQL',
       **'Data Science'**, 'Data Analysis and Modeling',
       'Statistics and data analysis']

new_list2: ['data', 'management', 'cloud', 'computing', 'big data', 'big',
       'data', 'data', 'analytics', 'data', 'visualization', 'predictive',
       'analytics', 'nosql', **'data science', 'data', 'science'**, 'data',
       'analysis', 'modeling', 'statistics', 'data', 'analysis']

---

I wrote the function to keep **'open source' & 'data science'** and break all the other tags into individual words. But apparently there's some logical flaw that not only keeps these two tags intact but also breaks these two tags separate words *(see bolded words above)*

Can someone help identify the issue here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in your if/if/else conditions:

```
if 'open source' in str(item).lower():
    tags.append('open source')
if 'data science' in str(item).lower():
    tags.append('data science')
else:
    item = str(item).lower().split(' ')
    tags.extend([e.strip("'():,&;+?][ ") for e in item if e not in remove]
```

Suppose item is 'open source' then you will go through the first if and append 'open source'. Then you will test VS 'data science' and go through the else bloc.

You will have to test with something like:

```
if ('data science' in str(item).lower()) or ('open source' in str(item).lower()):
    if ('data science' in str(item).lower()):
        tags.append('data science')
    else:
        tags.append('open source')
else:
    item = str(item).lower().split(' ')
    tags.extend([e.strip("'():,&;+?][ ") for e in item if e not in remove]
```

or, assuming `str(item).lower()` is exactly 'data science' or 'open source':

```
if str(item).lower() in ['data science', 'open source']:
    tags.append(str(item).lower())
else:
    item = str(item).lower().split(' ')
    tags.extend([e.strip("'():,&;+?][ ") for e in item if e not in remove]
```